# Why does enabling Paint Flashing substantially increase Frame rate?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[This is the code in question.](https://github.com/biosafetylvl5/frontend-nanodegree-mobile-portfolio) However, I can demonstrate the same effect on most website pages, this page being one of them.

When measuring the framerate with the FPS meter built into google chrome the frame rate is between 15 and 35. However, when one enables Paint Flashing, the framerate is an (almost) steady 60fps.

I am using User Timing API to measure the time taken to run the animation javascript, and there seems to be no noticeable difference between running with or without Paint Flashing enabled.

I have tested this using Google Chrome Beta Version 52.0.2743.41 beta (64-bit, Arch Linux) and Version 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit, Windows 10) and the results are consistent.

So, I have two questions:

1. Why does this occur
2. If this increases the performance of pages, why is this not present in the normal rendering process of chrome?

Pictures:

Without Paint Flashing:

[image: without paint flashing]

With Paint Flashing:

[image: with paint flashing]

Comment: Try to create a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will help you get answers faster because it's easier for others to reproduce the code of interest. For example, a Stack Snippet.

Comment: It is unclear if we need the entire GitHub project, or just *pizza.html* in the *views* directory (and associated files).  Best would be an [mcve] which we don't have to put a bunch of work into just to get to the point of being able to *begin* to look at the problem. Right now, the bar we have to jump over to just *start* helping is quite high.

Comment: I don't believe this is a question specific to the code that I am using and have seen the same effect on a variety of websites. Moreover, I can see the same effect on this very page. I will edit my question to make this clearer.

Comment: Do you have your GPU Acceleration flag  set to "off" ? Maybe the paint flashing does enable it anyway the flag is set.

Comment: Right now, all of my flags are set to "Default". Whether that means it is enabled or not, I do not know.

Comment: Ok, can repro, may be it's just because otherwise it has less than 60 frames to render per second ?

Comment: Is there any way for me to verify/test your hypothesis? It seems reasonable to me, but I can't accept it as correct rather than just a gander until I can produce verification.

Comment: @BSL-5, Did you find out more about this? As I've just noticed this too whilst identifying performance issues in a Vue app. I have a scrollable container with lots of comments inside. Scrolling in that DIV is quite laggy for whatever reason, FPS is ~20-30 avg. However, when I enable paint flashing, the FPS meter is consistently a solid ~60 FPS.

Comment: No, I haven't heard anything else pertaining to this odd phenomenon.

Comment: Problem still occurs. From monitoring my local machine I can see when painting is enabled a new process is created. Perhaps the fps monitor then watches the new process painting the boxes rather than the actual website? It would explain why the website doesn't consume more memory when painting.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=801714&can=2&q=component%3APlatform%3EDevTools%20paint%20fps&colspec=ID%20Owner%20Summary%20Modified%20Stars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been Available for over a year, [and has been marked "WontFix".](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=801714&can=2&q=component%3APlatform%3EDevTools%20paint%20fps&colspec=ID%20Owner%20Summary%20Modified%20Stars) The FPS meter in the compositor by design picks up any other work in the system before it, including paint flashing. The developers of chromium would need to move to an RAF-based or another form of FPS counting to not run into this issue.